# SAPUI5 ProcessFlow - Lanes only

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm trying to display a process status chain (e.g: stat1 -> stat2 -> stat3). 
To do that I am using ProcessFlow with lanes only.
For some reason, I only see the last lane.

```js
MyModel = {lanes: [{laneId: "lane0", iconSrc: "sap-icon://accept", position: 0, text: "Some Text"},
               {laneId: "lane1", iconSrc: "sap-icon://accept", position: 1, text: "Other Text"},
               {laneId: "lane2", iconSrc: "sap-icon://accept", position: 2, text: "Another Text"},
               {laneId: "lane3", iconSrc: "sap-icon://accept", position: 3, text: "Final Text"}]};


        <ProcessFlow
            id="processflow1"
            scrollable="true"
            lanes="{MyModel>/lanes}">           
            <lanes>
                <ProcessFlowLaneHeader
                    laneId="{MyModel>id}"
                    iconSrc="{MyModel>icon}"
                    text="{MyModel>text}"
                    position="{MyModel>position}" />
            </lanes>
        </ProcessFlow>
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Is there a better way to represent this using standard SAPUI5 controls?

Aviad

Comment: your code looks ok. https://jsbin.com/wamuhik/edit?js,output it must be something else

Comment: Found the answer - It was the order in which I set the data.